# Split using two delimiters

Tags: javascript, split

How to split using two delimiters. Below is my code where I am splitting the string using (). How to split both using `() and {(` in the below string.

```
var str = 'abc xyz() ab{( }) pp '
var res = str.split("()");
console.log(res); //[ 'abc xyz', ' ab{( }) pp ' ]
```

I have tried something like this, which does not split properly

```
res = str.split(/[\})\()/]/
```

I am expecting something like below

```
[ 'abc xyz', ' ab', '}) pp ' ]
```

If `str = 'abc xyz() ab{( }) pp bb yy{( kk llop'`, I want the output to be `[ 'abc xyz', ' ab', '}) pp bb yy{( kk llop' ]`. The split must happen only on the first occurrence.

Comment: In your expected output, you've left out a space in `ab`. Should be ` ab`.

Comment: Yes I missed it. Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = 'abc xyz() ab{( }) pp '

var result = str.split(/(?:\(\)|\{\()/);

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Something like:

```
str.split(/(?:\(\)|\{\()/)
```

You use `|` to specify either match `()` OR `{(`. The `?:` makes it non-capturing.

Comment: If str = 'abc xyz() ab{( }) pp bb yy{( kk llop', I want the output to be [ 'abc xyz', ' ab', '}) pp bb yy{( kk llop' ]. The split must happen only on the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Use Or `|`

```
'abc xyz() ab{( }) pp '.split(/\(\)|\{\(/)
```